# How to remove Netflix from Windows 7 Media Center menu?

Tags: windows-media-center, netflix

I'd like to remove the Netflix menu item in Windows Media Center 7's Movies section.

I saw recommendations for Windows Media Center Studio, but at the time of writing, [the website](http://www.adventmediacenter.com) is down.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have already installed and you'd want to remove/uninstall it, follow these steps.

Uninstall from Control Panel->Programs and Features->Vista Media Center vmcNetFlix Add-In.
Remove the following, if they exist:

```
C:\Program Files\Luttmann\vmcNetFlix
C:\ProgramData\vmcNetFlix_Data
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Luttmann\vmcNetFlix
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Luttmann\vmcNetFlix
```

You may also check in programs and features(Click **Start**>> **programs and features**) for any Netflix updates installed; if so remove them.

Check this link for known issues and limitations using Netflix in Media Center:

> http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistamedia/thread/00f7805d-4e5f-41f4-b968-055528283ef9

Comment: Thanks but these are some old instructions for Vista.  They don't apply to Windows 7.

Comment: They might.  Just try.

Comment: They don't apply to Win7 or 8 for that matter.